# How to create a cursor from a custom database helper

Tags: android, android-sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

I'm going through Griffith's *Head First: Android Development* book and a certain code is throwing a `Cannot resolve Symbol` error.

I am building a cursor from the custom database helper as per the instruction of the book.  This is the code that is throwing the error.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_drink);

        int drinkNo = (Integer)getIntent().getExtras().get(EXTRA_DRINKNO);

        try{
            SQLiteOpenHelper starbuzzDatabaseHelper = new StarbuzzDatabaseHelper(this);
            SQLiteDatabase db = starbuzzDatabaseHelper.getReadableDatabase();
```

It says `Cannot resolve symbol "StarbuzzDatabaseHelper"` even though StarbuzzDatabaseHelper does exist in my project.  This is code from the book.  Not mine.  I'm assuming that its an error from the book.  I tried this:

`SQLiteOpenHelper starbuzzDatabaseHelper = new SQLiteOpenHelper(this);` and it still didn't work.

This is my full code:

```
public class DrinkActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String EXTRA_DRINKNO = "drinkNo";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_drink);

        int drinkNo = (Integer)getIntent().getExtras().get(EXTRA_DRINKNO);

        try{
            SQLiteOpenHelper starbuzzDatabaseHelper = new StarbuzzDatabaseHelper(this);
            SQLiteDatabase db = starbuzzDatabaseHelper.getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor = db.query(
                    "DRINK",
                    new String[]{"NAME", "DESCRIPTION", "IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID"},
                    "_id = ?",
                    new String[]{Integer.toString(drinkNo)},
                    null, null, null);
            if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
                String nameText = cursor.getString(0);
                String descriptionText = cursor.getString(1);
                int photoId = cursor.getInt(2);

                TextView name = findViewById(R.id.name);
                name.setText(nameText);

                TextView description = findViewById(R.id.description);
                description.setText(descriptionText);

                ImageView photo = findViewById(R.id.photo);
                photo.setImageResource(photoId);
                photo.setContentDescription(nameText);
            }
            cursor.close();
            db.close();
        }catch(SQLiteException e){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Database Unavailable", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the database helper class:

```
public class StarbuzzDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DB_NAME = "starbuzz";
    public static final int DB_VERSION = 2;

    public StarbuzzDatabaseHelper(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, factory, DB_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        updateMyDatabase(db, 0, DB_VERSION);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        updateMyDatabase(db, oldVersion, newVersion);
    }

    private void updateMyDatabase(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion){
        if(oldVersion <1){

            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE DRINK ("
                    + "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                    + "NAME TEXT, "
                    + "DESCRIPTION TEXT, "
                    + "IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID INTEGER);");

            insertDrink(db, "Latte", "Espresso and Steamed Milk", R.drawable.latte);
            insertDrink(db, "Capuccino", "Espresso, hot milk and steamed milk foam", R.drawable.cappuccino);
            insertDrink(db, "filter", "Our best drink coffee", R.drawable.filter);
        }
        else if(oldVersion < 2){
            db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE DRINK ADD COLUMN FAVORITE NUMERIC");
        }
    }

    private static void insertDrink(SQLiteDatabase db, String name, String description, int resourceID){
        ContentValues drinkValues = new ContentValues();
        drinkValues.put("NAME", name);
        drinkValues.put("DESCRIPTION", description);
        drinkValues.put("IMAGE_RESOURCE_D", resourceID);
        db.insert("DRINK", null, drinkValues);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined the constructor for the **starbuzzDatabaseHelper** class to require 4 parameters as per :-

```
public StarbuzzDatabaseHelper(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, factory, DB_VERSION);
}
```

The attempt to instantiate an instance you are using :-

```
SQLiteOpenHelper starbuzzDatabaseHelper = new StarbuzzDatabaseHelper(this);
```

Whilst you could/should be using :-

```
StarbuzzDatabaseHelper starbuzzDatabaseHelper = new StarbuzzDatabaseHelper(
    this,StarbuzzDatabaseHelper.DBNAME,
    your_factory,
    StarbuzzDatabaseHelper.DB_VERSION
);
```

- i.e. passing 4 parameters (see below)
- Instantiating (creating an instance) your Database Helper rather than an instance limited by being an SQLiteOpenHelper instance.
- providing a method that can be resolved.

I would suggest that you alter the constructor to be :-

```
public StarbuzzDatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
}
```

Thus requiring the 1 parameter (the context)

and then use the following in your activity (activities) :-

```
StarbuzzDatabaseHelper starbuzzDatabaseHelper; //<<<< Class Scope for DBHelper

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_drink);

    int drinkNo = (Integer)getIntent().getExtras().get(EXTRA_DRINKNO);

    //<<<< try/catch can be confusing as exceptions may not stop when you very likely should.
    starbuzzDatabaseHelper = new StarbuzzDatabaseHelper(this);
    SQLiteDatabase db = starbuzzDatabaseHelper.getReadableDatabase();

    ...... rest of your code
```

#### Another issue

You also have an issue in that the your `insertDrink` method will not insert drinks because of a typo.

i.e. the columng when you create the table is `IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID INTEGER`, yet in the insert you call the column `IMAGE_RESOURCE_D`. I'd strongly suggest adopting the use of a single source (CONSTANTS) for table and column names and always using those wherever possible.

I'd suggest the following changes to your StarbuzzDatabaseHelper class this should then remedy/simplify matters :-

```
public class StarbuzzDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DB_NAME = "starbuzz";
    public static final int DB_VERSION = 2;
    public static final String TB_DRINK = "DRINK";
    public static final String COL_DRINK_ID = BaseColumns._ID;
    public static final String COL_DRINK_NAME = "NAME";
    public static final String COL_DRINK_DESCRIPTION = "DESCRIPTION";
    public static final String COL_DRINK_IMAGERESOURCEID = "IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID";
    public static final String COL_DRINK_FAVOURITE = "FAVOURITE";

    public StarbuzzDatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        updateMyDatabase(db, 0, DB_VERSION);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        updateMyDatabase(db, oldVersion, newVersion);
    }

    private void updateMyDatabase(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion){
        if(oldVersion <1){

            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE DRINK ("
                    + COL_DRINK_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                    + COL_DRINK_NAME + " TEXT, "
                    + COL_DRINK_DESCRIPTION + " TEXT, "
                    + COL_DRINK_IMAGERESOURCEID + " INTEGER);");

            insertDrink(db, "Latte", "Espresso and Steamed Milk", 1);
            insertDrink(db, "Capuccino", "Espresso, hot milk and steamed milk foam", 2);
            insertDrink(db, "filter", "Our best drink coffee", 3);
        }
        else if(oldVersion < 2){
            db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE DRINK ADD COLUMN FAVORITE NUMERIC"); //<<< rather then null
        }
    }

    private static void insertDrink(SQLiteDatabase db, String name, String description, int resourceID){
        ContentValues drinkValues = new ContentValues();
        drinkValues.put("NAME", name);
        drinkValues.put("DESCRIPTION", description);
        //drinkValues.put("IMAGE_RESOURCE_D", resourceID); //<<< NO SUCH COLUMN
        drinkValues.put(COL_DRINK_IMAGERESOURCEID,resourceID); // NO SPELLING ISSUES this way
        db.insert("DRINK", null, drinkValues);
    }

    // Alternative insert publicly available so activities can add drinks
    public long insertDrink(String drink_name,
                            String drink_description,
                            int resource_id,
                            double drink_favourite) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COL_DRINK_NAME, drink_name);
        cv.put(COL_DRINK_DESCRIPTION, drink_description);
        cv.put(COL_DRINK_IMAGERESOURCEID,resource_id);
        cv.put(COL_DRINK_FAVOURITE,drink_favourite);
        return db.insert(TB_DRINK,null,cv);
    }

    // method to return a Cursor with a sinhle drink as per the id
    public Cursor getDrinkById(long id) {
        String whereclause = COL_DRINK_ID + "=?";
        String[] whereargs = new String[]{String.valueOf(id)};
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        return db.query(TB_DRINK,
                null,
                whereclause,
                whereargs,
                null,
                null,
                null
        );
    }

    // method to return All drinks as a cursor sort according to drink name
    public Cursor getAllDrinks() {
        return this.getWritableDatabase().query(
                TB_DRINK,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                COL_DRINK_NAME + " ASC"
        );
    }
}
```

The following code has been used to test the above and is also an example of how to utilise the class :-

```
public class DrinkActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    StarbuzzDatabaseHelper starbuzzDatabaseHelper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); //<<<< change to your layout

        starbuzzDatabaseHelper = new StarbuzzDatabaseHelper(this);
        Cursor csr = starbuzzDatabaseHelper.getDrinkById(1); //<<< using 1 for testing
        if (csr.moveToFirst()) {
            Log.d("CURSORINFO","Drink name is " + csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(StarbuzzDatabaseHelper.COL_DRINK_NAME)));
            //<<<< replace the line above with your code >>>>
        }
    }
}
```

### Notes

- as it is unlikely that your database has any data due to the insert I'd suggest delete the database. This can be done by clearing/delete the App's data or by Uninstalling the App.

Comment: `public StarbuzzDatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, factory, DB_VERSION);
}` throws an error for `factory` because now its undefined.

Comment: Use null instead of factory. However, if you look at the suggested code at the bottom it uses null and this is the code that I suggest you utilise as you will still have issues if you ignore the latter code.

Comment: Thank you @MikeT.  I've accepted your answer and gave you an upvote.  If you think that this was a well-asked question, could you also give me an upvote?

Answer (score -1):

Instead of

SQLiteOpenHelper starbuzzDatabaseHelper = new StarbuzzDatabaseHelper(this);

try

StarbuzzDatabaseHelper starbuzzDatabaseHelper = new StarbuzzDatabaseHelper(this);

edit:
Add that to your helper class

```
 public StarbuzzDatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
}
```

Comment: This won't make a difference as it just changes the static type of the variable.

Comment: hmm ...

Have just checked it against one of my databases, the only thing I notice is that I have the following line in the constructor of the DatabaseHelper:
super (context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);


  // constructor
     public DBHelper (context context) {
         super (context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
         res = context.getResources ();
     }

Comment: And I think that could be the mistake?

Your constructor requires the parameters
public StarbuzzDatabaseHelper (Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version)

However, you only pass on the context
SQLiteOpenHelper starbuzzDatabaseHelper = new StarbuzzDatabaseHelper (this);